# How do I refresh a ListView in Android - onItemClick, Alert shown with Edit Text

Tags: android

I have a a list view that shows:

tag : 10
tagb : 20

When I click on an item, I get an Alert asking to change a value (EditText)
I set the value and click ok

1. How can I refresh the listview to show the change
2. How can I manually change the row and put the new value there eg tagb : 122?

BTW, The list of itemsand value comes from a result of a  REST call I make to a server

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Here is the code for the ListView:

setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

```
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, alarmName, deviceName, alarmDate,
            alarmSev);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    AlarmsTab.this);

            adb.setTitle("Acknowledge Alarms");

            adb.setMessage("Do you want to Acknowledge this Alarm? " + "\n"
                    + alarmName.get(arg2));
            alarmpos = alarmName.get(arg2);

            adb.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            CloseAlarm(asset, model, alarmpos);

                        }
                    });
            adb.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            adb.show();

        }

    });

    getAlarmsForAsset(asset);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: It depends on how you are creating the ListView. For instance, if the data is on an ArrayList (and you are using an ArrayAdapter), then you have to update the array and then invoke the notifyDatasetChange on the listview's adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your edit gets propagated into your data otherwise, when you do notifyDataSetChanged(); the list adapter will not pickup the right data upon refreshing.

That's where I would start looking first.